# Web based Java Editor & Compiler

Tags: java, compiler-construction, editor

I am building a web based editor for running simple java program on my personal interest. Not that I am stuck some where, successfully build nice GUI allows user to type java program , send to servlet where it is compiled (using Java Compiler API), loaded using custom class loader, executed, and returned the result as String. Application works perfectly for simple programs.

My question is about the improvement, How better can I implement the compiler part( as it is taking longer time to get the result back to user).

My additional options are below

1. Access Local JDK/JVM(if available) via applet
2. Inbuilt compiler in JavaScript (still be fantasy?)

I would like to know if I can make above options possible some how?

Comment: Maybe you could be interested: [Running Java in JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/blog/running-java-in-javascript/)

Comment: If the server fronting the IDE is also the server that holds the compiler, then performance can be adverse on large projects.  It may be worthwhile to separate the two onto their own VMs/servers instead.  I don't think I'd *ever* allow anything to compile on my own machine that I didn't have control over, it just seems like a security risk.

Comment: See [Help for the STBC](http://pscode.org/stbc/help.html#classpath) for some considerations of point 1.